# SQL Server Management Studio 17.9 font size not working

Tags: ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17.9 and want to increase my font size. 
When I go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > and then change the size of my font and press 'Ok'.
This way it's not working.

Comment: There's a show settings for in the top, i think that's where you can see what you made changes.

Comment: Maybe it's version problem. I tried SSMS 18.3. it's working properly.

Comment: I think? But good to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by zooming in,hold CTRL and scroll up or down till you get a suitable font size